# Report viewer query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on an mvc .net application and I want to create a report (.rdlc) with a parameter. The problem is that I can't find the query option for creating a dataset.
[image]

Comment: Embedded report viewer does not execute queries. It is the responsibility of the host. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms251724(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: So, how to use parameters in an embedded report viewer??

Comment: Create parameter using appropriate constructor (single value or multivalue) then call SetParameters ( see http://www.gotreportviewer.com/localmodeparameters/index.html )